# FSL error: fsl_vbm_1 -b problem imglob not found

Tags: home-directory, execute-command, mv

I am trying to run the command `fslvbm_1_bet -b` but get the following errors:

```
/usr/local/fsl/bin/fslvbm_1_bet: 1: /usr/local/fsl/bin/imglob: not found
/usr/local/fsl/bin/fslvbm_1_bet: 1: /usr/local/fsl/bin/imglob: not found
Done running BET, now running slicesdir:
Finished. To view, point your web browser at
file:/home/drnadine/Rotation/my_fsl_vbm/struc/slicesdir/index.html
```

I am assuming this has to do with imglob not being in the same folder/ directory as fsl? Should I try moving imglob to same folder as fsl (and how do I do this)?

When I checked `whereis fsl` I got the following:

```
fsl: /usr/local/fsl /usr/local/fsl/bin/fsl
```

Also, I am completely new to this so a step-by-step breakdown is extremely appreciated. Also, I have no idea what FSLDIR refers to nor do I know if I have it!

PS: I am on Windows 11 PC and I had to install linux Ubuntu through WSL so that FSL works. (FSL opens fine and so does `fsleyes` and `bet`. I also managed to view slicesdir images but couldn't perform `fsl_vbm_1 -b` or `-N`)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this and other issues in FSL. Apparently you just need to preface the commands that don't work with fsl5.0

Make sure to download these commands using:

```
sudo apt install fsl-5.0-core
```

If you installed FSL 5.0 using NeuroDebian repository, prefix "fsl5.0-" to the command you are trying to execute.
For instance, `fsl5.0-fsl` or `fsl5.0-Feat` instead of `fsl` or `Feat` respectively.
System: FSL 5.0.6 on Ubuntu 12.04 x64

Hope this helps you all!